# How to get deluge to open videos using mpv and folders using ranger?

Tags: mime-types

Right now when I right click to open a file under `deluge` it uses `VLC` for videos and `gwenview` as the file system explorer. I'd like to replace those by `mpv` and `ranger` respectively (`gnome-terminal -e ranger /path`). I've tried to mess with `./config/mimeapps.list` but to no avail. Any idea how to do this ?